# How to modify unicode code as it is a string

Tags: python, unicode

I have a list of partial Unicode codes for cuneiform characters.

for example I have, 12220 which python couldn't render to  which is what I wanted. Then I realized that adding \U000 in front of these partial codes creates results that I want. The problem is I can't modify unicode.

`"\U000{}".format(12220)` doesn't work. Clearly adding string to unicode is not possible. I don't want to hand merge 375 characters. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `\uxxxx` is just an escape sequence, it exists only on the sources (Python will see just the codepoint of that sequence. The function `chr` give the character of an integer (runtime).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
print(chr(int("12220", 16)))
```

`chr` function returns a character from int, and second paraemeter of `int` is the base it should be converted to.